# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "pasarse" y "pasar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, reflexivos

¿Qué diferencias hay en el uso del verbo *pasar* en estas dos oraciones?

1. **Se pasa** una mano por la frente.
2. **Pasa** una mano por la frente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Se pasa una mano por la frente.

Aquí se trata de una construcción reflexiva: el sujeto recibe la acción.

> Pasa una mano por la frente.

Es un imperativo: el sujeto no necesita recibir la acción.

Comment: @Leonardo Tengo que entendido que las construcciones impeesonales se usan con verbos intransitivos.

Comment: @Leonardo Con respecto a dar instrucciones, también se puede decir, *una pizca de sal es añadida*. Aquí, *añadir* es transitivo; es por esto que estas construcciones son posibles haciendo uso de *se*, que utilizan la transitividad del verbo.